Trying to install Ruby on Windows to download website
I've been working on a project that involves using Ruby. Despite several attempts, I haven't been successful in installing it.
I'm attempting to download a website with the Wayback Machine using a small app I found on GitHub: https://github.com/hartator/wayback-machine-downloader.
The instructional video I watched explained that I should download this app, place it on my desktop, and then install Ruby. It said to start Ruby with the command prompt. However, when I do this, I receive numerous lines of code that were not shown in the example video.
Please could someone explain to me what is it I am doing wrong here?
I've tried different version of the Ruvy installer but still getting line of code when clicking Start cmd with Ruby.
set "RI_DEVKIT=C:\Ruby32-x64\msys64"
set "MSYSTEM=UCRT64"
set "PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/ucrt64/lib/pkgconfig:/ucrt64/share/pkgconfig"
set "ACLOCAL_PATH=/ucrt64/share/aclocal:/usr/share/aclocal"
set "MANPATH=/ucrt64/share/man"
set "MINGW_PACKAGE_PREFIX=mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64"
set "MSYSTEM_PREFIX=/ucrt64"
set "MSYSTEM_CARCH=x86_64"
set "MSYSTEM_CHOST=x86_64-w64-mingw32"
set "MINGW_CHOST=x86_64-w64-mingw32"
set "MINGW_PREFIX=/ucrt64"
set "LANG=en_US.UTF-8"
set "PATH=C:\Ruby32-x64\bin;C:\Ruby32-x64\msys64\ucrt64\bin;C:\Ruby32-x64\msys64\usr\bin;C:\Ruby32-x64\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\babble\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;"


ruby is already installed just do 'ruby -v' you can see the ruby version you have insalled or do 'irb' to start interactive ruby session. what do you want to do after insatlling ruby is the question.

then you enter the following command in ruby terminal to install waybackmachine:
gem install wayback_machine_downloader

Run wayback_machine_downloader with the base url of the website you want to retrieve as a parameter (e.g., http://example.com):
wayback_machine_downloader http://example.com

you can see the example in screenshot below:


Hi Nabin, thanx for your reply.
I want to download a website using a Ruby gem
https://github.com/hartator/wayback-machine-downloader

ok give me a moment i will update the answer

@VincentvanRhyn hope the answer satisfies your need , for you to make your downloasd more precise you need to see the documenation  in the github that you shared me above and try diffrent flags as per your requiremnt. i have shown you the sample of what to do  in the answer.

Hi Nabin, I posted an error I am getting. Would you perhaps know moe about the specific error?
